# For Site to be ADA compliant does it need to have H1 tag or the highest tag can be H3?

Tags: html, web-standards, standards-compliance

I have a project to make site Ada compliant however, i can't find details on this specific question.

Do i need H1 tag to be compliant.

Comment: Why not use a styled `h1` if it really is your primary header and maintain a little bit of semantics (+better cross-browser experience)?

Comment: Many reasons, ex: others are using my html so less i change it the better. But does it violate compliance rules if first header tag is not h1?

Comment: Does "ADA" refer to [*2010 ADA Standards for Accessible Design*](http://www.ada.gov/regs2010/2010ADAStandards/2010ADAstandards.htm)?

Answer (score 1):

No, do not start with the H3 tag. You can lead some users to navigation error if you skip H1 and H2. They might think they've jumped too far, or the page is broken.
https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/page-structure/headings

H1 to H6 should not be used for font size, and you are free to style those to the size you need as long as you don't break other rules like not allowing the resizing of text by the user.

**Broader Context**

ADA and Section 508 do not specify any HTML requirements, so you must ultimately refer to W3C's guidelines. These guidelines link to the recommended HTML markup where it makes sense.

Web Content Accessibility Guidelines (WCAG) 2.0 https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG

From a practical standpoint, just pick your favorite tool and correct the major issues. Since any user can do the same thing, it's best to protect yourself before someone sends out an email casting doubts on your ability to make a proper website.
https://fae.disability.illinois.edu